# Dynamic stripe upgrade and downgrade

Tags: stripe-payments

I am working on a platform which allows service provider and agency to work together. Service provider supplies products to the agencies. The service provider buys a subscription which is annual and it can display upto 4 products on the site. Now, if they submit their product to an agency for approval and it gets approved, then there will be an additional fee of $x is added to the existing subscription. For each additional product, another fee will be added and that can be $y which means the approval fee cannot be same.
Similarly, downgrade can also happen if the service provider removes the product.

On May 1, 2023, the service provider pays a subscription fee of $40 for an year, it will be due on April 31, 2024.

On July 1, 2023, the service provider gets his 1 product approved from an agency. Now, the service provider has to pay additional $10 per year as approved product fee. The provider has to pay $10/12 months * 10 remaining months = $8.33 immediately. On April 31, 2024 , the service provider will be charged $50 for next year.

How can we handle this scenario in stripe ?

Comment: You probably want to calculate the approved product fee and charge the service provider for this separately. You can use Subscription Schedules to add the approved product fee to the next billing cycle: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules

You can also use test clocks to test this scenario out: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test-clocks

Comment: Thanks Laura, based on your answer, can you please confirm if service provider is only charged once in next billing cycle for both listing and approved product fee OR it will be 2 separate subscriptions ?

Comment: The service provider should be charged once in the next billing cycle. The schedule will essentially update their single subscription to contain two subscription items.